# Starting NTPD hangs when booting

Tags: boot

I have a Debian downloaded from http://www.raspberrypi.org/.

When I boot it up, it hangs when staring NTPD, and takes a few minutes to get to the login.

A message shows up after this showing its IP address.

I'm guessing there's something wrong with the boot order?

I tried to change the ntpd's "panic" time but it didn't work.

Adding

```
panic 5
```

to `/etc/ntp.conf` doesn't work.

Also, `ntpd -g` doesn't accept an argument either, so I don't know how to change its default threshold.

Has anybody experienced this before?

It seems that this is an issue that has happened on other Linux distributions on other platforms, but I don't think I've found a suitable solution yet.

Comment: Have you got `ntpdate` installed too?

Comment: I doubt this is a boot order problem, if it were everyone would be having this issue. You may want to try a new SD Card image.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Thanks! That was the problem, I almost forgot about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alex noted, if `ntpdate` is also installed, then removing it solves the problem.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on why this is the case? This answer appears incomplete.

Comment: I'm on the latest Debian (Wheezy) for RPi and removing `ntpdate` did not fix the problem. Running `ntpd -gq` causes the command prompt to simply hang; it never actually gets anywhere. I have to cancel the command using `Ctrl+C`.